# equivalent code to Sparse function matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, sparse-matrix

I want to translate a Matlab code to C++. I use for this the Matlab-Coder. However this Matlab code uses the function Sparse(triplet) that is not performed by the Matlab coder. So i decided to write my own Sparse function in order to be translated by the Matlab coder :

```css
function [ind,values]=test_new3_sparse(i,j,v,m,n)
  if(isrow(i)==0) i=i'; end
  if(isrow(j)==0) j=j'; end
  if(isrow(v)==0) v=v'; end
 
  k=1;
  A=zeros(m,n); %this line makes a problem when "m lines and the n 
                %columns" are too big

  for l=1:size(i,2)
   A(i(l),j(l))=v(l);
  end

  ind=zeros(m,2);
  values=zeros(1,m);

  for i=1 : size(A,1)
     for j=1:size(A,2)
         if A(i,j) ~=0
             ind(k,1)=i;
             ind(k,2)=j;
             values(k)=A(i,j); k=k+1;            
         end
     end
   end
  
end
```

This function I wrote works well when n and m are not important. However i have the error "out of memory" when they are too big. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is "too big"? Allocating a large non-sparse matrix inside your function to create sparse data would seem to defeat the purpose, no?

Comment: Yes, it would defeat the purpose, i did not pay attention to this, i think i try to run through the vectors without allocating the matrix A, ?

Comment: i modified by suppressing the allocation matrix, and it works well with high number of values. But my aim is to translate this :

Comment: ananass :> Can you please update or share the working code, I am not able to run this code. Me facing the same problem in matlab coder for not supporting the sparse(i,j,s,m,n) function.